# How to use unbound checkbox in a Continuous Subform - MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm fairly new to Access and having a really hard time figuring out each and every bit of it. Now I want to have a grid containing rows fetched from a query and a checkbox for every row. Here's what I want:

1. User should be able to select individual checkbox to select the row.
2. A "Select all" checkbox to select all rows.
3. Only upon clicking a button the rows must be updated

I have

1. Created a form.
2. Added a Continuous Subform and the Rowsource has a checkbox bound to a Yes/No field.

I'm stuck at this point. Please refer to the attached image and help me figure this out. Please suggest some good tutorials with practical examples. Thanks a lot.[image]

Comment: What is the actual problem? Implementing "Select all"? What have you tried? Finding tutorials isn't really on-topic at SO.

Comment: You can't really use a checkbox field bound to a Yes/No field - unless this is a one person database. The problem with using unbound fields is that if you change one in a datasheet or continuous subform, it updates them all. Finally - you can use the row selectors on the side - holding down the shift key to select multiples - but you can't cherry pick and skip rows - they have to be continuous. Best bet is to use @BitAccesser suggestion and the great example db with a class. Tough start to learn VBA - especially when tips are in German - but it does do exactly what you want

Comment: @Andre: I was trying to achieve exactly what BitAccesser's example is doing. Pardon my poor explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `clsCCRecordSelect`class from [SelectRecordsV2](http://www.ccedv.de/downloads/start.php?lang=en). There are samples in the [download db](http://www.ccedv.de/downloads/start.php?download=SelectRecordsV2.zip&lang=en), but comments are in german lang (I can translate if needed). If you need advice in implementing this to your form show form.name, form recordsource and control names of detail section (you need one control with unique values to assing the checkboxes to a record, can be invisible).

Comment: Nice examples - I didn't even know about these downloads. I'm going to go learn some German.

Comment: @dbm I wonder why this is not more popular! I can translate if necessary. By the way the `CurrentDbC` property (see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.databases.ms-access/AKNOQqL05iw/6qXL17WL6Z8J) paragraph 7) is not much known too, everyone uses ugly `CurrentDb`.

Comment: Thanks - I;ll check it out - and all the other examples - great ideas and code

Comment: @BitAccesser: That is so awesome. Thanks a lot mate. I haven't gone through all the files but I have a feeling I have found the holy grail I was looking for. I owe you man.

Comment: Unfortunately both of these links just return 'Not Found' errors four years later.