# Checkbox per row in multi user access database

Tags: ms-access

I have the following situation:

I have a many to many relationship.

For example an Employee Table, an Course table, and an relation-table inbetween.

Now I want that the user can select out of the course table his courses in a dialog form.

That means that the underlying table for my continous form inside the dialog is the course table. 
I want a checkbox in every row which indicates if the course is selected or not.
As I read it is not possible, to add an unbound checkbox, because they are just copies, and a select click would select all of them.
The solution would be to add an yes/no field to the underlying table courses.

But here I have the problem as I understand the matter, because I have several users using the database at the same time, that the underlying table will be updated if I click one checkbox and this update will select the value for all users which are using the dialog form concurrently, what I dont want.

So my question is, is there another solution to get a working checkbox per row in a multi user access database. 
There are two solutions which I could imagine:

1) The underlying table will be the relation table and in this every possible combination between employee and course will be saved together with a yes/no field. (but that would  be from a data view point  quite horrible)

2) If the changes to a checkbox would not be directly written back to the database table, I could discard them on saving and manually insert the relation records in the relation table. (Is that possible?)

Thanks for any solution proposals

Comment: In all cases you'll have to fully manage this with VBA. There are 2 approaches : if you really want checkboxes, then you need to work with an ADO disconnected recordset. If a solution where you just select the row in the datasheet is OK (so no checkboxes), you can work with DAO. But in this case you can only  select one row, or several concurent rows. I can provide you with a complete answer later following the solution you choose.

Comment: @thomasG what do you mean by, only select one row, or several concurrent rows? the checkbox is not necessary. But the user needs to select one or many rows, which i then want to save to the junction table when he presses a save button, so I need also a way to identify the choosen row

Comment: @Fionnuala I have a junction table, but initially it will not have any rows for  employee/course pairs. but I have to show all possible courses he could select. As above described if I put every possible combination into the junction table with a yes/no field, that would be possible, but it would add a lot of unnecessary data into the database, also I have to manage it everytime I add a new course or a new employee which could lead to errors in the database if someone would add employees or courses directly to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two good approaches:

1) This assumes that your database is split in a network backend + each user has a local frontend. This is the recommended setup for multi-user.

The frontend has a local table with Course_ID and a yes/no column.
A join of this local table with the Course table is the recordsource for your continuous form.

On loading, you copy the course ids into the local table, and set the existing relations to True.

On saving, you update the relation table.

2) Use a ListView control instead of a continuous form. It has inbuilt checkboxes. Loading and saving is done with a VBA loop.

Comment: I have chosen your first approach, and it seems to work quite well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I assume your form has a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN in its data source where some ID field is null if the specific Course/Employee combination does not exists in your relation table. Let's call it `LinkID`. Then  your checkbox should be something like `=NOT ISNULL(LinkID)`. While you will not be able to use the OnClick event for the user to check/uncheck this way, you can use the onMouseDown event to see if the user clicked the checkbox and take action accordingly.

That way you don't need an "all combinations" relations table, no temporary table and no Yes/No field. If a record with the Course/Employee combination exists the box is checked, if it does not exists, it is not checked. Adding and removing courses is done by adding and deleting records from the relation table.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [How to use unbound checkbox in a Continuous Subform - MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063647/how-to-use-unbound-checkbox-in-a-continuous-subform-ms-access-2013?s=2%7C1.3419). A class that binds an unbound checkbox. Better than listbox, because you have a form with all its benefits (sort, filter, edit, append).