# Select form rows using a checkbox on each row

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

The rows are grouped and ordered from a view with joins. I could add a field to one of the tables the view is based on, but this would write to the database. The selection should be made temporarily, and then the user clicks on one of the top buttons to generate a report based on the selected rows of interest.

I've added an unbound checkbox control in the Detail section. The onClick event reports the correct row IDs with MsgBox, the problem is that when I tick one of them, all of them are ticked visually. Like this:

[image: Top row is ticked. This results in all rows being ticked.]

I've tried applying SelectionV2 from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063647/how-to-use-unbound-checkbox-in-a-continuous-subform-ms-access-2013)'s answer, but when a checkbox is clicked, nothing changes and the status bar says the form is write-protected, even though I've allowed edits. The query is not updatable, but I don't want to. I just want to select rows.

Comment: Show forms code, especially`objRecordSelect.InitSelect` (Form_Load), checkbox is bound to`=fnGetSelection([NameOfIDControl])`

Comment: I'm not using SelectionV2. It can only use tables as recordsources, not queries, and the ID field must be numeric.

Comment: What makes you think that?

Answer (score 0):

Unbound checkboxes on continuous forms are usually bound to an expression, as I assume is the case in SelectionV2.

In that case, you can't use the `Click` event, because checkboxes bound to expressions are non-updateable and don't fire the `Click` event.

Use the `MouseDown` and/or `MouseUp` event instead. Those fire on the beginning and end of a click, and do work for checkboxes bound to expressions.

Comment: Thanks. I started out with them unbound, and this gives the behavior in the screenshot, so I put code in _Click to save which row was clicked, or removed it if already saved, then set the checkbox state to whether the row was saved. Then I tried changing to an expression and remove the _Click code, but whatever expression I use, I get "Form is write protected" and the Checkbox doesn't change state.

Comment: Eh... You should bind the controls to an expression, and change the result of the expression on the click event. You should not directly change combo box values as that doesn't work.

Comment: When unbound, and with no code, the checkboxes behave as in the screenshot. I have to read out which rows are selected somehow. If the checkboxes behaved like loose, unbound checkboxes I could, but it seems impossible to put any unbound control on a row without all of those controls being changed when one changes.

Comment: Yes, obviously. That's why you need to bind them to a function that gets the state, and use a separate function to set the state, as SelectionV2 did, like I said.